# include tag not up-to-date on App Engine 1.6.5

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm running Google App Engine 1.6.5 and according to the release notes, Django 1.3 is supposed to be supported. However my {% include %} tags can't accept context parameters; I get the following error. I've checked my django version which is 1.3.1 when app engine is running locally. I was fine on Python 2.5. By the way, I am importing django using use_library('django', '1.3') and also have the following line in my app.yaml:

libraries:
- name: django
  version: 1.3

Any ideas ?

Error:

```
line 89, in render
    t = _load_internal_django(template_path, debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 163, in _load_internal_django
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 160, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(template, origin, template_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 173, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock', 'endblock %s' % block_name))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 693, in do_for
    nodelist_loop = parser.parse(('empty', 'endfor',))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 828, in do_if
    nodelist_true = parser.parse(('else', 'endif'))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 210, in do_include
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag takes one argument: the name of the template to be included" % bits[0])
```

Comment: It seems you are using the webapp.template module? That isn't affected by the specified Django version, it always uses Django 1.2.5.

Comment: Thanks Guido! You are right. It is actually deprecated. I will switch to Django templating.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum is there a way i can get webapp to use Django 1.3 ?

Comment: Never mind, I think I got my answer. I am just going to need to change my templating system.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as pointed out by Guido the templating system I was using which always uses 1.2.5. The solution is to change my templating system to Django or Jinja ...